# How to generate multiple tabs from array and send them with form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, tabs, submit

I'm running on a booking system which is caused me headache for a couple of days ago. I am trying to find the solution for this project but none of them works. So could you please suggest some ideas? The form conditions are:

1. Able to book multiple rooms in the same times.
2. Each room must have it's own guest info.
3. All of the guest and booking detail is sent by clicking submit button.

To have tabs generated. I coded:

```
$room_name=array("T3","T4","T5","T6");
foreach($room_name as $val){
echo "<li>$val</li>";
}
```

So the result will looks like:

[image]

Now the problem is. I want to send all of the element in a booking form (from Villa No. to Remarks) to the server but I'm stuck with some conditions:

1. I can't put the villa name on each form and send them as array.
2. To put a hidden input in a form I need to place it under  which is already have before to get some of booking info, check-in/check-out, for instance.

Please give me some recommendations on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure which accepts all inputs and call that in your code. Go with ASP.Net the better one for developers.

Comment: Rajesh, I'm running on PHP.

Comment: You can try like this:  <?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$datepicker = $_POST['datepicker'];

mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die ('Error: ' . msql_error());
mysql_select_db ("xxxx");

$query="INSERT INTO allymccoist (id, firstname, lastname, email, datepicker) 
VALUES ('NULL', '".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$datepicker."')";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error Updating database');

echo "Database updated with:" .$firstname. ""  .$lastname. "" .$email. "" .$datepicker. ;

Comment: Ally McCoist? If you want to post code it's better to edit it into your answer then post it as comments

Comment: @Rajesh Thank for the script but I'm stuck on sending those booking form elements to a server. Not about the connecting to DB.